# AngularJS: forEach http get data - wait for other method untill all data from loop is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have such code:

```
      var commentAuthorIds = [];
      $scope.commentAuthors = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.news.Comments, function(el) {
        if (angular.isDefined(el.AuthorId)){
          commentAuthorIds.push(el.AuthorId);
        }
      });
      commentAuthorIds = $filter('unique')(commentAuthorIds);
      var promises = [];
      angular.forEach(commentAuthorIds, function(el) {
        promises.push($scope.getCommentsAuthorData(el));
      });
      $q.all(promises).then(function(){
        console.log('all data loaded!');
        angular.forEach($scope.news.Comments, function(el) {
          angular.forEach($scope.commentAuthors, function(subEl) {
            if (el.AuthorId === subEl.Id){
              el.Author = response.FirstName + ' ' + response.LastName;
              el.Thumbnail = response.Thumbnail;
            }
          });
        });
      });

      $scope.getCommentsAuthorData = function(userId){
        $http.get('/app/' + $scope.company.Id + '/users/' + userId, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .success(function(response) {
          $scope.commentAuthors.push(response);
        });
      };
```

and i need to call `angular.forEach($scope.news.Comments, function(el) {...` only after `$q.all(promises).then(function(){...` are loaded.

what i do wrong? my code didn't work(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getCommentsAuthorData dont return a promise... add return before $http

```
$scope.getCommentsAuthorData = function(userId){
    return $http.get('/app/' + $scope.company.Id + '/users/' + userId, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  };
```

based on this:

> The all function returns a promise for an array of values. When this
>   promise is fulfilled, the array contains the fulfillment values of the
>   original promises, in the same order as those promises. If one of the
>   given promises is rejected, the returned promise is immediately
>   rejected, not waiting for the rest of the batch.

this could be a problem in your case.... so using this $q extension could solve this issue [add this to your application](https://github.com/ohjames/angular-promise-extras)
then you can do this:

```
$q.allSettled(promises).then(function(responses){
      angular.forEach(responses,function(response){
            if(response.status!="rejected"){
                 $scope.commentAuthors.push(reponse.value);
            }else{
                 console.log(response.reason);
            }
      });
});
```

Comment: hm... didn't work
also: what if i get 404 or another error in getCommentsAuthorData ?

(for example i have 50 users, and one of them is deleted - i get 404 and promise is 'broken')

Comment: ofc you can check for error inside the promises array..... loop trough the results before set the commentAuthor value

Comment: hm... i didn't understand: how to do this? what exactly U mean?

Comment: i ve edited my answer... now it work also with rejected promises